# Boot Manjaro as a Guest VM or on Physical Drive

Tags: linux, virtualbox, drivers, virtual-machine, manjaro

#### Desire

I have a computer that has a Windows and a Manjaro boot drive. I would like to be able to access my Manjaro boot drive from windows, but also be able to boot directly to the Manjaro drive. So far I can do this, but cannot get the video drivers to work on both the virtual and physical boot without about an hour of hacking when switching between the two.

#### System Details

- GPU: NVidia/Intel
- Host: Windows 10 Enterprise
- "Guest": Latest Manjaro i3 (regularly updated)
- KVM: Latest VirtualBox

#### Question

1. What is needed to switch between the two?
2. Can switching between the two be automated depending on whether Manjaro is being virtualized?
3. Questions 1 and 2 may be too machine specific, is there a way, in Linux, to determine whether a machine is virtualized?

I have tried to find the answer to these questions online, and found enough detail to get the virtualbox drivers working, then the nvidia/intel (non-free) drivers working, but am struggling to get the virtualbox drivers working again.

Comment: You're essentially moving your Manjaro between two different computers.  VirtualBox emulates most of the hardware and it really only virtualizing the CPU.  It's not passing through the physical hardware to the VM, so that's why you're seeing those issues. VirtualBox does support limited PCI passthrough, but only on Linux hosts.  More info here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough

Comment: Passthrough in't really possible since my windows drive is bitlockered and I need it to be my primary OS. I can probably figure out what settings need to change to get it to work on both physical and virtual boot so I can write a script to make those changes. Is there an easy way to tell whether the machine is virtualized?

Comment: Based on some other information that I've looked up, I think I have found what I need. I will write an answer as soon as I get things working reliably.